# Atoms with energy differences corresponding to wavelengths 19.05 cm, 24.45 cm and 25.48 cm

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, space, gps

I was just wondering whether there are any known atomic transitions in Oxygen, Nitrogen, Hydrogen or Helium atoms/ions which emits wavelengths in any of the regions: 19.05 cm, 24.45 cm and 25.48 cm.
 These wavelengths are exactly the wavelengths used in GPS broadcasting and I was looking into the any possibility of these wavelengths being absorbed or emitted when the GPS signals passes through our ionosphere.

Comment: Did you look up emission lines for said transitions?

Comment: The absorption spectrum of the atmosphere is pretty well documented.  If it doesn't show any lines at those wavelengths then it unlikely any of its main constituents has absorption there. (And if they do, they're not strong enough to affect GPS transmissions)

Comment: I haven't looked up for the emission lines since I don't know whether to look up. Is there any source like the Astronomical Almanac which documents all the known absorption and emission lines?

Comment: I don't know actually whether people have considered the quantum nature of radio waves since the people whom I have talked to believed that radio waves don't have any effect since the wavelengths are very large as compared to the quantum domain. Moreover, the theory of radio propagation through the atmosphere or ionosphere has been dealt (so far) only with classical wave approach and not any quantum theory in play so far.  I just wanted to look into the matter more deeply actually.